# Write a .wav with byte in Python

Tags: python, mysql, byte, wav

I am trying write a .wav file in python. 
Actually, my MySQL database has a blob data (.wav file) and I am getting that blob file in a bytearray. I want to write again blob to .wav. My code block.

```
Wave_Byte = bytearray()
cursor=open.cursor()
sql = "select Wav from voice where Email='xxxx@gmail.com'"
cursor.execute(sql)
resultOfWindows = cursor.fetchall()
for rows in resultOfWindows:
    Wave_Byte=rows[0]



savefile=open('example.wav','wb')
savefile.write(Wave_Byte)
savefile.close()

cursor.close()
open.close()
```

I got this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/On-LinePython.py", line 47, in 
    savefile=open('example.wav','wb')
TypeError: 'MySQLConnection' object is not callable

Comment: You have overwritten `open` somewhere before your code.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you've redefined `open`, the python built-in, as your connection name because you're doing `cursor=open.cursor()`. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now. :) (I am a noob...)